# $n-$th singular homology group of a space with path connected components

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Suppose that path connected components of $X$ are $X_a$'s. Then, $H_n(X) \cong \oplus_a H_n(X_a) $. Why is this true?

$H_n$ here denotes $n$-th singular homology group.

I understand that if $C_n(X) $ denotes free Abelian group generated by maps $\sigma^n_b$ from n simplices $\Delta^n\to X$,then indeed we have $C_n(X) \cong \oplus_a C_n(X_a) $.
This is by path-connectedness of $n-$ simplices and continuity of $\sigma^n_b$'s.

I don't understand how to show $H_n(X) \cong \oplus_a H_n(X_a) $ from here.

I defined a map $f$ that takes $$ \sum n_b\sigma_b^n+Im (\partial _{n+1})\in \frac{\ker \partial_n}{Im \partial_{n+1}}$$ and sends it to $$\bigoplus \left (\sum n_b\sigma_b^n+Im \partial_{n+1}^a \right )\in \oplus_a H_n(X_a).$$ It is clear that $\ker f=\cap_a  Im \partial_{n+1}^a$. But I am not sure how to show that $\ker f=Im \partial_{n+1}$ and that $f$ is surjective. If these are shown, then the result follows by the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 5):

You say that you can see that each $C_n(X) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha C_n(X_\alpha)$. Can you see that these isomorphisms are compatible with the chain complex structure? That is, write $\varphi_n : C_n(X) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha C_n(X_\alpha)$, do you see why the following "ladder diagram" commutes?

[image: a ladder diagram whose top row is C_n(X) and whose bottom row is the sum of the C_n(X_\alpha)]

The key insight, which you've already noticed, is that an $n$-simplex $\sigma$ in $X$ must be contained in a single $X_\alpha$. But then the boundary $\partial_n^X \sigma$ is *also* entirely contained in $X_\alpha$ so that it equals $\partial_n^{X_\alpha} \sigma$, the boundary as computed in $X_\alpha$.

Now, if you know some homological algebra, we can finish immediately. After all, this is exactly the definition of a **chain isomorphism** $\varphi_\bullet : C_\bullet(X) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha C_\bullet(X_\alpha)$ and one can show that isomorphic chain complexes have isomorphic homology, and that homology commutes with direct sums. Then we see that
$$H_n(X) \cong H_n(C_\bullet(X)) \cong H_n \left ( \bigoplus_\alpha C_\bullet(X_\alpha) \right ) = \bigoplus_\alpha H_n(C_\bullet(X_\alpha)) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha H_n(X_\alpha)$$

---

We don't need that level of abstraction here, though. Instead we can check by hand that this data gives us an isomorphism on homology. Indeed, you should first check that we get an isomorphism on homology from this ladder diagram. To check this, check that $\varphi_n |_{\text{ker}(\partial_n^X)} : \text{ker}(\partial_n^X) \cong \text{ker} \left ( \bigoplus_\alpha \partial_n^{X_\alpha} \right )$ (and similar for images).

Next, use the fact that $\text{ker} \left ( \bigoplus_\alpha \partial_n^{X_\alpha} \right ) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha \text{ker} \left ( \partial_n^{X_\alpha} \right )$ (and similar for images) to conclude the claim.

---

I hope this helps ^_^